# Localizing for sub-cultures on WP7 not getting picked up

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

I am trying to localize my wp7 application and I need to have different strings for `de-DE` and `de-AT` because there are some language differences between those two cultures even though the basic settings are the same.

I did the following to achieve this:

1. Created an `AppResources.resx` file for the default English text
2. Created an `AppResources.de-DE.resx` file for the German text
3. Created an `AppResources.de-AT.resx` file for the German text for Austrian sub culture
4. in the *Assembly Information...* in the project properties I set English as my *Neutral Language*
5. I closed the solution, opened up my `project.csproj` file and changed the `<SupportedCultures/>` to the following: `<SupportedCultures>de-AT;de-DE</SupportedCultures>`
6. I added a new Class `LocalizedStrings`, registered it in Application.Resources in App.xaml and changed the output string accordingly.

Both the Emulator as the handset are set to Austrian Locale, `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();` returns **de-AT**, but regardless of that the texts defined in `AppResources.de-DE.resx` are used and not the ones defined in the file for the Austrian culture.

Any idea how I might solve this issue?

Comment: You also need to add `en` to the `SupportedCultures`, just for the record.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was covered by the Neutral Language setting.

Comment: The marketplace submission used to disagree with me about that. So better safe than sorry.

Comment: If you remove de-DE file from the project, does the de-AT get picked up? This would test your build process isn't skipping the file or something.

Comment: I have not tried submitting without it, but I do believe Claus is correct, that you need the en in the csproj file.  Also, have you tried setting the culture in code to see if it picks it up there?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'd be interested in seeing the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx), not the CurrentCulture!

That is the property that controls what resources get loaded for interface!

The value of CurrentUICulture should match the one selected in the phone/emulator *Settings -> Region+Language -> Display Language*.

Ideally, you can always override the system imposed CurrentUICulture by setting a different CultureInfo on [Thread.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).